# Spring Cloud Data Flow | Rabbit MQ exchanges not getting tied up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic here:

I have created a flow using this topology:

A | B | C

This is the application.properties of A:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.requestChannel.destination=events-exchange
```

This is the application.properties of B:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=events-exchange
```

C is an OOTB log sink app.

With this setup, A | B is fine but C is not getting any logs. Although, B is delivering the message to the correct exchange, the link from B | C is disjoint.

Please note that I have not supplied the above properties during deploy time. They are static application.properties within the jar.

How should I let SCDF to join the apps correctly? What's the best practice/recommended approach around this? We have many apps that needs to be joined using the Rabbit Middleware and looking for a simpler, less error-prone approach. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,

What are your binding destination for B's `outbound` and C's `inbound`. Given, C is OOTB log app, does log's `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination` point to the same `exchange` that B's output (configured via `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<outboundChannelName>.destination` is bound to?

Comment: B's outbound is: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=work.out`

Comment: Does C have `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=work.out`?

Comment: B's outbound is: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=work.out` I haven't supplied any deploy-time properties for 'C'. As a side note, if I don't supply any of these, does SCDF automatically joins them based on streamName_appName convention? Supplying too many properties (or a props file per se) which defines the sequence somewhat feels difficult to track although the DSL reads A | B| C . What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the output of B to `work.out`, then you'd need to override the input of C as well. What Spring Cloud Data Flow does is to set both the input and the output of adjacent apps to a common value (derived from the stream/app name). If you are overriding one of them, apps become disconnected as you have noticed. While we do intend to support overriding intermediate destinations in a better way in the future, `A | B | C` relies on relinqushing control of the binding of `input/output` to Spring Cloud Data Flow (you can override that, but as you noticed, you need to be explicit on both ends). As an alternative to renaming destinations mid-stream, you can use named destinations: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-explicit-destination-names.html .